# how to find lowest unique bidder and display username of that lowest unique bidder

Tags: php, mysql

My data base is
        https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYBXk.jpg
    hey i m new here in php and i don't know how to find lowest unique bidder for a auction of a product and i want also display name of username of that lowest unique bidder.
please help me i have tried but some code that are follow

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("gunjanbid", $con);
$sql="SELECT * from bid";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$username=$result['userName'];
$serial=$result['serial'];
$low_sql = "SELECT bidamount,userName, COUNT(bidamount) as bid_count 
     FROM bid 
     WHERE bidamount<'{$serial}' AND bid_count=1 AND auction='{$username}' 
     GROUP BY bidamount"; 
$low_query = mysql_query($low_sql) ; 

$low_bids = array(); 
if (mysql_num_rows($low_query) > 0) 
{ 
    $lower_bid_exist = true; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($low_query)) 
    { 
        $low_bids[$row['bidamount']] = $row['bid_count']; 
    } 
} else { 
    $lower_bid_exist = false; 
}  

?>
Lowest Unique Bidder :<?php echo $row['userName']; ?>
```

Comment: will you help me how can do it plz.

Comment: what does $serial contain?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT bidamount,userName, bidamount as bidamount 
     FROM bid WHERE bidamount = (SELECT MIN(bidamount) FROM bid) ORDER BY closing_date LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This wouldn't appear to solve the uniqueness issue. You would still need to do a HAVING on a distinct count of the bid amount

Comment: plz tell me how it can be happen plz help

Comment: how does that solve uniqueness - it just hides it. For any given bidamount there must only be 1 username with it in the auction. Your query does not check that the amount is unique anywhere there

Comment: This query will be work fine, just remove lst limit from the query,

SELECT bidamount,userName, bidamount as bidamount 
     FROM bid WHERE bidamount = (SELECT MIN(bidamount) FROM bid) ORDER BY closing_date

Comment: It won't work... Guys, read his question... the lowest UNIQUE bid... Not the lowest bid as of the closing date... The lowest bid might be $0.01 but 100,000 people might have it...

Comment: @trent :  bidamount = (SELECT MIN(bidamount) FROM bid) This will find the lowest unique bid but it will then get 100,000 people among them this query decide who is the first.

Comment: @IleshPatel - then you've completely missed the point of his request... He's trying to emulate a pretty common auction format - if anymore than 1 person has this amount, it's no longer in the running, the bid is forfeited for ALL users. Also, tell me how, if 100,000 have placed this bidamount do you consider it unique?

Answer (score 0):

OK. So, firstly, you need to approach this issue with a tiny bit of planning.

Your requirements are:
- The bid amount must be unique
- You want to select the lowest bid amount

There are quite a few ways to do this. I will show you the simplest (SQL wise) way to solve your issue in a single query (with subquery).

This is NOT the best way - as I would ordinary suggest two separate queries, but this will get you what you want in a single row return.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e978/10

SQL becomes:

```
select 
  bidamount,
  username
from
  bid
where
  -- for the auction in question
  auction = '$username'
  and bidamount = (
    select
      min(lowest_bid.bidamount)
    from
      bid lowest_bid
    where
      lowest_bid.auction = '$username'
    group by
      lowest_bid.bidamount
    having
      count(distinct lowest_bid.username) = 1
    order by
      bidamount
    limit 1);
```

Comment: hey trent i din't understand what is auction here in case of my table database and i also want to sort the lowest unique bid on product id because every product have different id number

Comment: Sorry mate - my answer shows you how to do it based on the code you provided us - which one would only assume is your own... If you can't figure out what is going on in the code above, I can't help you any more, you need to go and learn SQL... Or, alternatively, you can hire someone on oDesk or eLance to do this for you.